# Which is the correct sentence

Tags: sentence-choice

> I'm just looking forward to the holidays which is coming soon.
>
> I'm looking forward to the coming soon holidays.

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Questions which ask "which is correct?" without identifying any particular point of grammar or usage that is confusing are considered proofreading and are explicitly off-topic. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Native speaker.)

Both sentences have multiple errors, unfortunately.

In both sentences, since "holidays" is plural, "is" should be replaced with "are". A single holiday is coming soon, but holidays *are* coming soon.

The second sentence is simpler to correct, so let's do that one first:

---

> I'm looking forward to the coming soon holidays.

This sentences uses "coming soon" as an adjective to describe "holidays", which is incorrect. Replace "coming soon" with "upcoming", which is an adjective that means the same thing

---

> I'm just looking forward to the holidays which is coming soon.

I'm not sure why the word "just" is here. It doesn't add anything to the sentence. Without additional context, I think it should be removed.

With this construction, there are two additional related issues. First, should there be a comma after "holidays"; second, should the sentence use "which" or "that".

Let's look at the second issue first. "Which" is the beginning of a clause that is *optional* for understanding the meaning of the sentence. Using "that" means that the clause is *required* for understanding the meaning.

I'm going to borrow an example from the [Grammarly blog post](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/which-vs-that/) about this:

> My bike that has a broken seat is in the garage.
>
> My bike, which has a broken seat, is in the garage.

The first sentence, using "that", implies that the speaker has more than one bike. The speaker is indicating that the *specific bike* -- the one with a broken seat -- is the one that is in the garage. The information about the broken seat is *required* to know which bike the speaker is talking about.

In the second sentence, the speaker does *not* imply they have more than one bike. The broken seat is just a way to *describe* the bike, and that description could be removed without changing the meaning of the sentence.

So, in the sentence about holidays, is the speaker *identifying* the holidays, or *describing* them? If the speaker is identifying the holidays, then "that" is appropriate.

Because the sentences use "which", it sounds like the speaker is *describing* the holidays. That's totally valid usage. But if that is the case, then there should be a comma before "which". Optional clauses have commas at the beginning and end -- though the end comma doesn't apply here, since the end of the clause is also the end of the sentence.

> I'm looking forward to the holidays, which are coming soon.

A comma is *not* required if the sentence uses "that":

> I'm looking forward to the holidays that are coming soon.

Using "that" implies that the speaker is *only* looking forward to the holidays that are coming soon. Maybe they are not looking forward to the holidays that are coming further in the future.